# After submitting form its showing success message on different page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

After clicking the submit now button I can't get the message above the form. Please help me out in this. Please anyone.

Here is index.html form:

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
   <div class="messages"></div>
   <div class="controls">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
               <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
               <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
               <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="form_need">Please specify your need *</label>
               <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                  <option value="">-----</option>
                  <option value="Request quotation">Request quotation</option>
                  <option value="Request order status">Request order status</option>
                  <option value="Request copy of an invoice">Request copy of an invoice</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
               </select>
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
               <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdX5uQUAAAAAEPAP03K3_jafzIdoOFSblSgm2um" data-callback="verifyRecaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="expiredRecaptchaCallback"></div>
               <input class="form-control d-none" data-recaptcha="true" required data-error="Please complete the Captcha">
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div> 
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send btn-danger-gradiant mt-3 mb-3 text-white border-0 py-2 px-3" value="Send message"><span> SUBMIT NOW <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></span></button> 
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="text-muted">
               <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is the contactus.js:

```js
$(function () {

    window.verifyRecaptchaCallback = function (response) {
        $('input[data-recaptcha]').val(response).trigger('change');
    }

    window.expiredRecaptchaCallback = function () {
        $('input[data-recaptcha]').val("").trigger('change');
    }

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

This is the contact.php form:

```php
<?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// configure
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// ReCaptch Secret
$recaptchaSecret = '6LdX5uQUAAAAAEakfeeS4jlKkOjvSaqrawNp4gUD';

// let's do the sending

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception,
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually

        $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }

        // All the neccessary headers for the email.
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );

        // Send email
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: change your `action="contact.php"` to `action="#"`

Comment: i have tried it but no change it will just reload the page and does not show the suscessfully submitted messsage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message is on the an another page because you use action="contact.php".
Try to remove that part of code.Also remove the portion with form

```
<input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send btn-danger-gradiant mt-3 mb-3 text-white border-0 py-2 px-3" onclick="addYourFunctionhere()" value="Send message"><span> SUBMIT NOW <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></span></button> 
      <script>  
function addYourFunctionhere(){
  var getform_name= $("#form_name").val()

  //and here use ajax to send the var from top

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {"username":getform_name},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't change anything.. any other suggestion please!!!

Comment: I modify you some part of code, but not the entire code

Comment: it depends of your version of php,bassicaly you need to use mysql_connect()

Comment: if you are connected from php to your database you can use something like mysql_query("INSER INTO <table_name> VALUES(<your forma values separated with , >)")

Comment: for more detail try to visit w3school.com or php site there you have a lot of code exemple that you can try an learn them to use